# Add Confluence release documentation to Jira version via API

Tags: jira-rest-api, confluence-rest-api

When making a JIRA release, I would like to generate release notes as a Confluence page. This can be achieved in the JIRA Releases UI by selecting `Create Release Notes` from the version, but I cannot find an equivalent API under Confluence or JIRA API documentation.

Is the same functionality possible via API?